Manga/comic/dj/webtoon about "syphoning" the blood
I'm looking for a manga title. I will list all the things I remember about it. I hope I'm not mixing up more titles into one.

It was black and white manga, with classic-book pages' style (not so sure right now)

I was reading it around 2010

Second of the main duo was called a "syphon/siphon" or something like that, or there was blood syphoned from them (probably both?). They met the first main character when they (the second) was running away from some sort of cult or something?

There were monsters roaming around. I don't remember what lured them or at what time of the day, if there was a specific time at all

Action took place in a somewhat post-apocalyptic city where nature was starting to gain back  territory (I'm not 100% sure about that)

The first character was probably a delivery person, if I remember correctly

At some point the "syphon/ed" character was kidnapped and the first character was looking for them in an abandoned skyscraper/other tall building. They may have encountered other "syphon/ed" character/s that were drained dry? And they found their "syphon/ed" bound to a chair, or something like that. I know it's vague but I have a memory of the goldfish so all that information are a lot for my standards.


I looked for it for almost, or even more than, 30 hours. I tried different key-words, different languages... to no avail. I would think it was some sort of a fever dream if there weren't for 2 facts. First - my friend that I already knew when I was reading this has some vague memories of me telling them the plot like that. Second - my other friend that I didn't know back then, after reading my description, recalled that they also read something like that around the same time I did.
I don't care in what language the title would be, I just need one that will more or less match that description (especially draining blood) before I will go insane.

You should mention where else you've asked and anything you've already ruled out; https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/1ghzv8j/manga_about_syphoning_the_blood/

sorry, didn't think about it, I also asked in a second reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1girm2k/tomt_mangacomic_2010_manga_about_syphoning_the/
I also tried to get help form AI in finding the title and then with translations the keywords to japanese, mandarin, cantonese, thai, vietnamese and german so I can search in different languages. I search in english and in polish without the help of chatGPT, because just finding the title with a help from chatGPT or GeminiAI was fruitless
I am that desperate

I still haven't found the title. Any help will be appreciated ^^

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
